# jquery to filter multi level json

Tags: jquery

Please help me to write a jquery to filter below json file on property **DisplayInPPE=true** from below input json,

Below is my input file and expected output file

Input Json

```
[
   {
      "CategoryName":"Application Group",
      "CategoryServices":[
         {
            "ServiceOid":"8bc2f18c-2a9a-4286-a8bc-619384c4f8c2343",
            "ServiceName":"MFA",
            "CloudType":[

            ],
            "CloudTypesCount":0
         },
         {
            "ServiceOid":"2aa3da21-9d9e-423c-86e8-7123a8f5140c332",
            "ServiceName":"Azure Privileged Identity Management",
            "CloudType":[

            ],
            "CloudTypesCount":0
         },
         {
            "ServiceOid":"f5661f9f-65cf-4349-bfe1-e2b6605ab5a3",
            "ServiceName":"IDML",
            "CloudType":[
               {
                  "Id":15,
                  "ServiceOid":"f5661f9fj-65cf-4349-bfe1-e2b6605ab5a3s212",                  
                  "RequiresPPT":true,
                  "DisplayInPPE":false,
                  "DisplayInPROD":true
               },
               {
                  "Id":16,
                  "ServiceOid":"f5661f9fj-65cf-4349-bfe1-e2b6605ab5a3",                  
                  "RequiresPPT":false,
                  "DisplayInPPE":true,
                  "DisplayInPROD":false
               },
               {
                  "Id":17,
                  "ServiceOid":"f5661f9fj-65cf-4349-bfe1-e2b6605ab5a3444",                  
                  "RequiresPPT":true,
                  "DisplayInPPE":false,
                  "DisplayInPROD":true
               }
            ],
            "CloudTypesCount":3
         }
      ]
   }]
```

OutPut Json

```
[
   {
      "CategoryName":"Application Group",
      "CategoryServices":[
         {
            "ServiceOid":"f5661f9f-65cf-4349-bfe1-e2b6605ab5a3",
            "ServiceName":"IDML",
            "CloudType":[
               {
                  "Id":16,
                  "ServiceOid":"f5661f9f-65cf-4349-bfe1-e2b6605ab5a3",                  
                  "RequiresPPT":false,
                  "DisplayInPPE":true,
                  "DisplayInPROD":false
               }
            ],
            "CloudTypesCount":3
         }
      ]
   }]
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1:

Ok guys i managed to solve this myself. Posting the the code if any one want to refer in feature

```
filteredres=jQuery.grep(data, function (element, index) {
                            element.CategoryServices= jQuery.grep(element.CategoryServices, function (element2, index2) {
                                if(element2.CloudTypesCount>0)
                                {
                                    element2.CloudType= jQuery.grep(element2.CloudType, function (element3, index3) {                        
                                      return element3.DisplayInPPE==true;

                                    });      
                                    return (element2.CloudType.length!=0);
                                }        
                            });   

                            return (element.CategoryServices.length != 0);
                        });
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "write my code for me" site. If you share the code you have written, maybe someone will help. Without, no one will.

Comment: Please try solving the problem for some time and share whatever you've managed to do. Everyone will be happy to help you fix it.

Comment: managed to solve it... thanks :)